# how to select only one check box with JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ClientAccountIsHospitality, new { @type = "checkbox" })
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ClientAccountIsHospitality)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ClientAccountIsRetail, new { @type = "checkbox" })
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ClientAccountIsRetail)
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
                $(this).closest(".checkboxContainer").find("input[type='checkbox']").not(this).prop("checked", false);
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            });
        });
        </script>
```

I was hoping when a user selects a check box, the other check box will de-select, if it is selected.
Problem with this code is user can select a check box but cant de-select it again. either by selecting another check box or trying to un select the selected box

**NOTE** I have used checkboxes through out my site and would like to stick to this. I do not want a radio button. thaks

Answer (score 3):

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(e){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(':checked').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);

    }
    else{
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/8WuQH/)

Comment: thats great thaks for the help, but i still cant un check a box, after checking it. Only un checks if i select the other box?

Comment: sorry, then try to remove  e.preventDefault();

Comment: ahh thats great thank you...the only problem I have now is there is another checkbox on the page but I dont want it to apply to this. any ideas on what to do?

Comment: <div class="form-group">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ClientAccountIsActive)@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ClientAccountIsActive)</div>